# Cannot convert from void to char

Tags: java

I just started programming in Java so I'm still pretty much a noob. I tried to check if a sentence contains a specific word. This is my code:

```
public static void run(String sentence) {

    System.out.print("Please provide a string");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String str1 = sc.next();

    if(str1.contains("Andy")) {
        System.out.print("V");
    }
    else {
        System.out.print("X");
    }

}
```

And I have to run the following test:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class Assignment1_3Test {

@Test
public void runTestOnlyAndy() {
    char output = Assignment1_3.run("Andy");
    assertEquals('V', output);
}

@Test
public void runTestNoAndy() {
    char output = Assignment1_3.run("This does not contain the word An-dy");
    assertEquals('X', output);
}

@Test
public void runTestNoText() {
    char output = Assignment1_3.run("");
    assertEquals('X', output);
}

@Test
public void runTestAndyAtTheEnd() {
    char output = Assignment1_3.run("This contains the word Andy");
    assertEquals('V', output);
}

@Test
public void runTestAndyMiddle() {
    char output = Assignment1_3.run("This contains the word Andy in the 
middle of the sentence");
    assertEquals('V', output);
}
}
```

Now when I run this test I get the following error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to char. I don't know how to fix this, but I think it's just a small thing and it really frustrates me that I don't know how to fixt it. So if someone could give me tip on how to fix this, it would be really appreciated!

Comment: Have you learned how to `return` things?

Comment: More specifically, the `run` method just prints to the console, which can't be assigned to a variable outside of the method

Comment: `public static void` is the standard signature for `main`, but remember that `void` means *"returns nothing."*  So you can't assign the result of that method to any variable.  Change the return type from `void` to `char` and then return a value, instead of printing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `run` method to the one below. Note that you are not using the `string` parameter. You should probably refactor to the refactored version instead.

```
public static char run(String string) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please provide a string");
    String str1 = sc.next();
    if(str1.contains("Andy")) {
        return 'V'
    } else {
        return 'X'
    }
}
```

**Refactored version:**

```
public static char containsAndy(String string) {
    return string.contains("ANDY") ? 'V' : 'X';
}
```

If you want your method to be easy to test, you should not read the sentence inside the method, but provide it as argument. See the below `main` for an example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.print("Please provide a string");
    String sentence= sc.next();
    System.out.print("Sentence contains Andy: " + containsAndy(sentence)); 
}
```

Comment: Hi sir, this indeed looks like the answer to my question. But now the test doesn't complete, it seems like my code doesn't read the input it gets from the test ("This does not contain the word An-dy") like these sentences.

Comment: @JansenN Are you sure your test is not stuck waiting from input at `String str1 = sc.next();`? If it is, either provide input or refactor to `refactored version`.

Comment: Doesn't the test already provide input with this line of code: `char output = Assignment1_3.run("This contains the word Andy");` ?

Comment: It does, but your tested method blocks at `String str1 = sc.next();` and waits for input from console. I think that's why your test does not complete.

Comment: But how can my method obtain the input from the test then? Because I thought this was the right way to the it, but apparently it isn't :)

Comment: It should get the tested sentence as argument. You should not read it in the method.

Comment: See the updated answer for an example. In this way, you can use your method with a sentence received from `Scanner` in your `main` and also can test the method against specific inputs without blocking.

Comment: I changed my code now (see main post), but now I get the following error: `The methode run(String[]) in the type Assignment1_3 is not applicable for the arguments (String)`

Comment: If you don't remove this `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); String str1 = sc.next();` you won't be able to run tests without manually providing input for each test.

Comment: But how does my method obtain the input for each test then? Should I completely remove the scanner? Because I don't need to test my method with manually provided input.

Comment: Then yes, you should completely remove the scanner from the tested method.

Comment: I probably sound pretty stupid, but I still don't get how my method will obtain the input from each test. You said that my method should receive the sentence as an argument, but I'm not quite sure how to do that?

Comment: By the method signature `public static char run(String sentence)`

Comment: Oh my god, so all the time it wasn't even necessary to use that freaking scanner. Well it finally worked now. Thanks a lot!!